# How to Attach PDF or Doc file in UI Path tool(Robotic Automation Process)

Tags: uipath

I am trying to send mail from UI path tool with attachment of PDF or DOC file.

[image: Please check the image to verify my work flow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just provide an absolute path to a file. You can make use of variables, too - as the following example shows:

[image: SMTP Activity]